# How to use the event-based file system listener with Spring in a Rails 4.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring-gem

I'm using [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) 1.1.3 with the default [`Polling`](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/6d120af97469ab47efe313c0d94b416671e822b5/lib/spring/watcher/polling.rb) Watcher in a Rails 4.1.4 application. Now I'd like to give the event-based file system listener a try, but can't figure out how to configure this properly.

When adding the listen Gem (1.3.1) to the Gemfile and setting `Spring.watch_method = :listen` in an initializer, the Watcher doesn't change. Checking `Spring.watcher` will return an instance of `Spring::Watcher::Polling`.

So, where's the right place to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [configure Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring#configuration) before Rails loads, set `Spring.watch_method = :listen` in `config/spring.rb`. Setting it in an app initializer is too late—you've already "sprung" by then.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! While trying your suggested method I stumbled over https://github.com/jonleighton/spring-watcher-listen, which also works like a charm.